# Flask. Критичны для исключения

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Критичны ли исключения в production, которые возникают в маршрутах (app.routes)?

Иногда при передачи неверных данных с клиента (например асинхронный post запрос) может возникнуть исключение на сервере. В DEV режиме данная ситуация сильно критична, т.к. flask & python предоставляет много информации (вплоть самой строчки кода с ошибкой).

Нужно ли все исключения обрабатывать, когда имеется риск получить ошибку?
Вопрос важен, т.к. я не имею представления, какие действия происходят при получении исключения.

Если в prod режиме скрипт просто завершается, а route возвращает response.code не 200, то исключения можно не обрабатывать (действительно так?).

---

Приведу пример:

```
@bp.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def available_dates():
    data = request.json
    result = []
    if data:
        from_date = datetime.strptime(data['from'], '%d.%m.%Y').date()
        to_date = datetime.strptime(data['to'], '%d.%m.%Y').date()
        ...

    return jsonify(result)
```

Если в данном случае, поступает POST запрос с неверными данными, то вызовется исключение. Клиентской стороне данное исключение нет смысла обрабатывать (так задумано). Если для клиентской стороны важен response.code == 200 и полученные данные, то я смело могу игнорировать исключение?

Answer (score 0):

Все зависит от требований. В них должно быть указано что именно делать в той или иной ситуации, какие исключения являются ожидаемыми, а какие должны вываливать код 500. Также в требованиях должно быть указано что делать в этих случаях. Логгировать в файл или например отправлять сообщение на мыло. А вот не зависимо от этих требований вы должны обеспечить скрытие технической информации, настроек и деталей реализации от клиента чей запрос вызвал ошибку. А так же обеспечить стабильность работы без возникновения отказа в обслуживании.

Примером может служить сайт на Джанго, который в зависимости от настройки DEBUG может обеспечить вас сообщением на почте с отладочной информацией, а клиенту будет отдана страница с кодом 500.

Я не говорю истину в последней инстанции. Все что я сказал может и должно быть подвержено критике. Так как это лишь мои умозаключения.

Comment: С логированием все ясно, так же . Flask, как и Django умеет автоматически высылать отладочную информацию на почту или сохранять в файл.

Вопрос больше стоит, нужно ли вообще подобного рода ошибки обрабатывать, если клиент проверяет response – если ошибка или пришли пустые данные, то окно с ошибкой общее.

Comment: добавил пример для ясности.